Stuck in a dark room and can’t get out
So I just did something in Inscryption, and now I’m softlocked or something (except I think it was supposed to happen).
Ok. So I beat the guy you play the cards with in the cabin (he has no name so far) after walking through the forest path. After taking a photo of him and turning him into a card, I went over and looked at it, then couldn’t do anything else with it. I looked around the room and saw the giant glowing card with a plus sign inside a person stamped on it. I went over and inspected that, and then all light in the room disappeared (almost. There’s a small light through a door or something, but I can’t reach it). I’ve gone everywhere I could in the room, spamming every button along the way, but nothing I do does anything.
Is this supposed to happen? If not, what do I do? If so, what do I do next?

That is what is supposed to happen. Worry not, you are not softlocked!
The card with a person with a plus sign is the New Game menu option. When you initially started playing, you might have noticed that the New Game option was grayed out and produced a glitchy error noise when you tried to select it—the only way to start playing the game is to choose Continue.
Now that you have touched that New Game icon, you are able to select New Game in the main menu. Though in any other game that would mean "Return me to the start of play, as if I had just launched the game for the first time" (thus undoing all of your progress), in this instance it is the intended and necessary way to proceed to rest of the game.

So what should OP do now? Close current game and start a new ng+ game or can he escape from the black room in his current save? (I didnt play that game)

@ChrᴉzremembersMonica At this point in the dark room you can open the menu and choose "Start Screen". When in the Start Screen, the disabled "New Game" button will become enabled and you can start a new game, to proceed with Inscryption.

@Chrᴉz remembers Monica It's not "New Game+". OP is essentially done with Chapter 1 of the game, and the way to start Chapter 2 is to select New Game. This won't create erase their current save and create a new one; rather, they will still be on the same save file, playing the "beginning" of the game which is only accessible after you beat the old man at cards in the cabin.
